# NHibernate avoiding N+1 with deep level

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following objects:
A -> B -> IList -> D -> IList and so on..

If I fetch the list of A, NHibernate does an inner join on B. That's okay.
But C is fetched with the N+1 problem.

I tried this:

```
var query = session.Query<A>()
    .Fetch(x => x.B)
    .ThenFetchMany(x => x.C)
    .Distinct();
```

But then he did 117 fetches instead of 5 before. For example E is now not eagerly loaded. Or C is ten times in B instead of one time.

What's the best approach for such a situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Ayende's article [Solving the Select N+1 Problem](http://ayende.com/blog/3732/solving-the-select-n-1-problem), start use NHibernate Profiler, it could detect N+1 issues [Alert: Select N+1](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/SelectNPlusOne)